# Why does Rasterize introduce a new area into my Graphics object?

Tags: graphics, bugs, rasterize

**Bug introduced in 13.1 or earlier**

---

I am using `Rasterize` on a `Graphics` object (because I want to count the number of black and white pixels). However, applying it introduces a new, blank area into the rasterized version of the `Graphics` object (see the image below). Why is this and how to avoid it?

[image]

EDIT: The code used to generate the `Graphics` object:

```
posList = Table[
   {RandomReal[{0, 1}], RandomReal[{0, 1/29}]}
   , {n, 1, 100}];
graphics = Graphics[{
    EdgeForm[None], Black,
    Table[Ellipsoid[posList[[n]], {0.5/29, 0.5/29}/2], {n,1,100}]
   }, PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1/29}}];
```

Comment: When generating ``Graphics``, use ``Graphics[..., PlotRangePadding -> 0]``.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but it didn't make any difference unfortunately.

Comment: It might help if you provide your code for generating graphics. There are also other options, like ``ImageMargins`` and ``ImagePaddings``.

Comment: I've included it.

Comment: I reproduce the issue with version 13.1.0 on Windows 10 x64, but not with version 12.3.1 on the same machine. Hence it is a regression bug. Please report it to the support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reproduce the issue with version 13.1.0 on Windows 10 x64, but not with version 12.3.1 on the same machine. Hence it is a regression bug. Please report it to the support.

As a workaround, you can specify explicit `ImageSize` for `Graphics`:

```
posList = Table[{RandomReal[{0, 1}], RandomReal[{0, 1/29}]}, {n, 1, 100}];
graphics = Graphics[{EdgeForm[None], Black, 
    Table[Ellipsoid[posList[[n]], {0.5/29, 0.5/29}/2], {n, 1, 100}]}, 
   PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1/29}}, ImageSize -> {720, 25}];

Rasterize[graphics]
```

[image: screenshot]

Specifying `ImageSize` for `Rasterize` also works:

```
posList = Table[{RandomReal[{0, 1}], RandomReal[{0, 1/29}]}, {n, 1, 100}];
graphics = Graphics[{EdgeForm[None], Black, 
    Table[Ellipsoid[posList[[n]], {0.5/29, 0.5/29}/2], {n, 1, 100}]}, 
   PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1/29}}];

Rasterize[graphics, ImageSize -> {720, 25}]
```

[image: screenshot]

It looks line the bug is caused by too small default image height of your `Graphics`:

```
is = Differences[Rasterize[Annotation[graphics, "Output", "Region"], "Regions"][[1, 2]]][[1]]
```

> ```
> {360., 12.4138}
> ```

Specifying sufficiently large `ImageSize` fixes the problem even if the original small `RasterSize` is requested:

```
Rasterize[graphics, ImageSize -> 2 is, RasterSize -> Round@is]
```

[image: screenshot]